# How to get an object from one class to another class?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android developing.
I am trying to program an application related to auction.
I studied this open-source application sample and try to customize it.
http://product.hubspot.com/blog/building-an-auction-app-in-a-weekend

It applied Parse as server to upload and retrieve data.

I need to copy an object called AuctionItem from one class to another class for getting variables(objectID) in that object.

AuctionItem.java

```
@ParseClassName("Item")
public class AuctionItem extends ParseObject {

    public AuctionItem() {}

    public String getObjectID() { return getString("objectID");}
    public String getName() {return getString("name");}
    public String getDescription() {return getString("description");}
    public String getDonorName() {return getString("donorname");}

}
```

ItemListActivity.java

```
public class ItemListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     List<AuctionItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AuctionItem>();
     BaseAdapter adapter;
     DataManager data = DataManager.getInstance();
     String listQuery = DataManager.QUERY_ALL;

     public void setup() {
         allItems = data.getItemsMatchingQuery(listQuery, this);
         adapter = new AuctionItemAdapter();
     }

     public class AuctionItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
         @Override
         public AuctionItem getItem(int position) {
              return allItems.get(position);
         }
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              final AuctionItem item = getItem(position);
         }
     }
```

DataManager.java

```
public class DataManager {
     private List<AuctionItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AuctionItem>();
     static DataManager singletonInstance;
     public static final String QUERY_ALL = "ALL";

     public DataManager() {}

     public static DataManager getInstance() {
         if (singletonInstance == null)
           singletonInstance = new DataManager();

         return singletonInstance;
         }
     public List<AuctionItem> getItemsMatchingQuery(String query, Activity context) {
         if (query.equals(QUERY_ALL)) {
         return allItems;
         }

         else {
             ArrayList<String> queryWords = new ArrayList<String>();
             queryWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(query.split(" ")));

             ArrayList<AuctionItem> results = new ArrayList<AuctionItem>();
             for (AuctionItem item : allItems) {
                 for (String word : queryWords) {
                    if (word.length() > 1 &&
                     (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()) || item.getDonorName().toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()) ||
                      item.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())))
                    results.add(item);
                 }
              }

              return results;
         }
    }
}
```

I want AuctionItem item this object and call objectID from another class.
I tried to make another Auction called copy and program it likes this:

```
public AuctionItem copy;
copy = item;
```

But when I use other class to call this variable, it said:
Non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context.

What should I do to get this object.Please help!!

Comment: due to your "static DataManager"

Comment: Thanks for answer. So what should I do for my code?

Comment: why you are using static key word here?

Comment: I follow the original code only. Sorry I don't the reason too.
But I tried to delete static of DataManager, its still not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your Object so:

```
public AuctionItem copy;
String item = copy.getObjectID();
```